# Pandas Pivot Table: String and Integer filter

Tags: python, pandas, filter, pivot-table

I am trying to implement a filter on my pivot table builder producing a table: `table` that can filter out both integer (<, <=, >, >=, =, and !=) and string values (!=, =) according to user spec:

```
attribute = raw_input('Attribute to filter: ')
conditional = raw_input('Conditional to filter by: ')
limit = raw_input('Value to filter by: ')
```

The filter works if the attribute I select consists of integers by doing the following (`"All Values"` is the suggested input if no filter is needed):

```
if attribute != "sAtt1" and attribute != "sAtt2" and attribute != "sAtt3":
    limit = int(limit)

if conditional != "All Values" or conditional != "all values":
    if conditional == "!=":
        table = table[table[attribute] != limit]
    elif conditional == "=":
        table = table[table[attribute] = limit]
```

And so on for remaining conditionals.

This doesn't work however when the `attribute` consists of strings.

sAtt1, sAtt2 and sAtt3 are the attributes consisting of strings (which I want to remain unchanged) but when (for example) sAtt1 is used the following error occurs:

```
KeyError: "sAtt1"
```

This confuses me as this error is not being returned for attributes consisting of errors - any ideas where the KeyError is coming from?

**Edit**

Here is an example of data I have been testing this on (with columns both containing strings and integers):

https://www.dropbox.com/s/gyvho9cmxqx4nta/Football.csv?dl=0

Comment: This error is essentially saying the column you're trying to filter on does not exist. Without any sample data and expected output we can't really help beyond that.

Comment: I will add some data now - I didn't think the error could be with the data though as the inputs are working for column titles for columns containing integers

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1**
I'd build a map of operations

```
op_map = {
    '<': pd.Series.lt,
    '<=': pd.Series.le,
    '>': pd.Series.gt,
    '>=': pd.Series.ge,
    '==': pd.Series.eq,
    '!=': pd.Series.ne
}
```

Then you could use it like this:

```
op_map[conditional](table[attribute], limit)
```

---

**Option 2**
You could also build a `query` string.  But you won't be able to use `=`.

```
table.query('@attribute @conditional @limit`)
```

Comment: A much more elegant solution than mine but the `KeyError` is still being returned. I will include a sample of the data to try and add to the question.

Comment: The `KeyError` is telling you that `'sAtt1'` is not a column in the dataframe `table`

Comment: That's the part I don't understand though. When I run my pivot table builder over for example the now linked csv file, if I build one using Country, League and HomeWins as the values and then filter League to only include the Algeria-Ligue-1 the same `KeyError` occurs when the column clearly exists

Comment: @Andrew_000 try to observe the column values with `print(table.columns)`  There may be white space around the text that is goofing things up.  If there is, `table.columns = table.columns.str.strip()` should fix it.

Comment: This makes sense and I did think of this earlier but unfortunately this still hasn't solved it. I'm somehow still getting a `KeyError`... Any other ideas?

Comment: Post a comment where you paste the output from `print(table.columns)`

Comment: Is that the table being the dataset or the pivot table itself?

Comment: This is the output from print(table.columns) for the total dataset:                                Index([u'Sport', u'Country', u'League', u'Year', u'Season', u'Team', u'Games',
       u'HomeWins', u'HomeDraw', u'HomeLoss', u'HomeRatio', u'AwayWins',
       u'AwayDraw', u'AwayLoss', u'AwayGoalsDiff', u'Unnamed: 15'],
      dtype='object')